How to Run Commands in a Singularity from Shell Script
I wish to run a Python script in a singularity container.
In particular, I have attempted writing the following in the shell script
singularity shell <name.sif>
python3 <python-script.py>

I expected the python script to be run within the singularity container, but it outputs a segmentation fault (which occurs when I run the script on its own, outside the singularity container). However, when I try to do this manually by executing the commands individually, it works well. I would like to know how to shell script this properly. Thank you!

You're starting an interactive Singularity shell. The command after that will be executed when you exit the shell.
Use singularity exec to execute a command inside the container.
singularity exec <name.sif> python3 <python-script.py>

